# Mouse cursor becomes locked during keyboard input

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm attempting my first shot at using Unity. This is my first foray into game development and 3D environments. I'm following the tutorial for the survival shooter located here: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/player-character?playlist=17144

I went to try mouse movement, which should change the direction of the player object, but found that the player does not change direction.

I have even tried copying the tutorial author's code directly, using it in its entirety and overwriting my original script. Their code can be found in the link.

Adding `Debug.Log("Raycast not hitting");` to an else block in the `Turning` function causes the debug message to fire during each FixedUpdate, regardless of whether the mouse has been positioned over the floor.

Answer (score 1):

Since you directly copied all scripts, I'm assuming that their are no issues with your scripts. This means that this issue is most likely located somewhere in your scene. The boolean controlling player, `Physics.Raycast(camRay, out floorHit, camRayLength, floorMask)`. The else statement you used assures you that this function is returning false. I think the most likely reason this may be is that you do not have an object in the scene that has its layer set to `floor`. The aforementioned function will automatically return false if the RayCast does not find an object with a layer of `floor` within a range of `camRayLength`units. So, find or create an object that covers the entirety of the floor and set its layer to `floor`. I would also recommend looking at the scripting API documentation for Physics.Raycast so that you can better understand whats going on in the code. Here's a link to Unity's documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html